# sorting record of a model based on attribute of associated model in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a stock model and supply model and stock belongs to supply model.

I want to sort stock records based on "date_received" attribute of supply model

```
Stock.where("seller_id = ? AND status = ? AND product_id = ?", @seller_id, "Approved", list_item.product_id)
```

I am getting error for below:

```
Stock.includes(:supply).where("seller_id = ? AND status = ? AND product_id = ?", @seller_id, "Approved", list_item.product_id).order("supply.date_received")
```

Comment: it should be table name in order clause like supplies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there just should be `supplies` instead of `supply` Try,

```
Stock.includes(:supply).where("seller_id = ? AND status = ? AND product_id = ?", @seller_id, "Approved", list_item.product_id).order("supplies.date_received")
```

Comment: I am getting this error:   PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "seller_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ... ON "supplies"."id" = "stocks"."supply_id" WHERE (seller_id ...

Comment: you must have seller_id in both tables. `stocks.seller_id` will solve your problem.

Comment: @BhimasenRautaray use table name with column name in where clause query like 
 "stocks.seller_id = ?" this will resolve the exception